# Trying to get an image from div id in android studio

Tags: android, image, html, getelementsbytagname

I honestly don't even know where the proper place to begin with this would be, so I've been fumbling around with it.  I've seen several *similar* posts, but I haven't been able to get anything to work.

What I'd like to do is use the div id to get a specific image from a web site without having to hard code the image link in.  For instance, one of the things I'm trying to do this for is a webcomic. I'd like to be able to use the div id="comic-1" tag and get the img src="..." it's connected to.

I'm very open to methods of doing this.  Here's what I tried most recently:

```
wView.loadUrl("...");
wView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
wView.getSettings().setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);
wView.getSettings().setUseWideViewPort(true);
wView.getSettings().setSupportZoom(true);
wView.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
wView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient(){

@Override
public void onPageFinished (WebView webView, String url)
{
    webView.loadUrl("javascript:document.getElementById('comic-1').src;");
}
```

But it doesn't load the image.  It just loads the site, as normal.

Also, it's a bit of an off-shoot, but I'm trying to figure out how to use these tags in general.  Another thing I'd like to do is delete something within a tag.  Here's what I've tried for that:

```
webView.loadUrl("javascript:(function() { " +
                "document.getElementsByTagName('header')[0].style.display=\"none\"; " +
                "})()");
```

I should've included the HTML block I was working with. I don't have an image id to work with, unfortunately.

```
<div id="comic-1" class="comicpane"><a href="" title="..."><img src="..." alt="..." title="..."/></a></div>
```

Comment: Isn't `comic-1` a `div` tag? You're trying to access the `src` of a `div` tag and not of the `img` tag. `div` tag does not have the `src` attribute. You could instead give an id to the `img` tag and access it using `getElementById('image').src`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this:

HTML  block:

```
<div id="comic-1">
     <img id="image" src="http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/compman.gif" width="107" height="98">
     <img id="smile" src="http://www.w3schools.com/tags/smiley.gif" width="107" height="98">
</div>
```

Accessing it:

```
webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
webView.loadUrl(URL);
webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient(){
    @Override
    public void onPageFinished(WebView webView, String url)
    {
        webView.loadUrl("javascript:var s = document.getElementById('smile').src;document.write(s);");
    }
});
```

Going by the example shown above, this will write the image source in the document.

**[EDIT]**

```
var parent = document.getElementById("comic-1");
var child = parent.getElementsByTagName("img");
document.write(" image 1 = " + child[0].src + " image 2 = " + child[1].src);
```

Comment: Thanks. That makes sense, but I guess I should've included the HTML block I was working with.  I don't have an image id to work with, unfortunately.

<div id="comic-1" class="comicpane"><a href="" title="..."><img src="..." alt="..." title="..."/></a></div>

Comment: Well, if that's the case, use `getElementsByTagName()` Check my edited answer.

Comment: Thanks again. Last question.  I only recently realized that the code was intended to find and display the source, which it does perfectly.  I'm trying to actually display the image in the webview, though.  How would I do that instead of just displaying the url to it?

Comment: So just output the image instead of displaying the `src`. No big deal in that. `document.write("<img src=" + comic[0].src + " /> ");`